# Realloc error, reading from pipe failed error, closing pipe error

Tags: c, string, file, pipe, fork

I tried to write a code in C using forks and pipes where the program creates four processes that communicate with each other trough pipes. The communication is based on the following communication tree :

```
  1
 / \
 2 3
 \ /
  |
  4
```

The first process reads **n** words from a file called **input.dat**, where n is given as an argument. The first process sends the words to the second and third process using different pipes.

The second process reads the words from the pipe and counts all the vowels word by word. If the number of vowels is even, the process swaps every vowel by pair of two (no modifications needed in case of odd number), then attachs the number of vowels to each word. 
I already asked a question related to this, here is the link with examples : [How to count number of vowels from file word by word and attach the results to the words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028883/how-to-count-number-of-vowels-from-file-word-by-word-and-attach-the-results-to-t)

The third process does the same except with consonants.

Both second and third process use the same pipe to send the modified words to the forth process that will print the modification to a file named **output.dat** .

After each process of reading, writing or modification the processes print their pid along with what they did to a file named **log.dat**

When I execute the program I get all sort of errors related to closing of pipes or reading from pipes. I looked trough the code many times but can't figure out what could be causing the errors.

Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int str_count_in_chars(char *start, char *end, char *chars) {
    int count = 0;

    for (; start != end; count += !!strchr(chars, *(start++)));

    return count;
}

void str_swap_in_chars(size_t str_len, char **str, char *chars) {
    int front,back;
    for ( front = 0, back = str_len - 1; front < back; front++) {
        if (strchr(chars, (*str)[front])) {
            for (; !strchr(chars, (*str)[back]); back--);

            char tmp = (*str)[front];
            (*str)[front] = (*str)[back];
            (*str)[back--] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

char *file_to_str(FILE *fin,int n) {
    int buf_len = 64;
    char buf[buf_len];
    char *str = malloc(buf_len);
    str[0] = '\0';
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    fgets(buf, buf_len, fin);
        if (!(str = realloc(str, i * buf_len))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d realloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            exit(1);
        }

        strcat(str, buf);
    }

    return str;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pfd[2],pfd1[2],pfd2[2];

    FILE *f =fopen("log.dat","w");

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Usage:\n%s <number>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *p=argv[1];
    while(*p != '\0')
    {
      if(*p<'0' || *p>'9')
      {
       printf("%s is not a number!\n",argv[1]);
       exit(1);
      }
      p++;
    }


    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    FILE *g;

    if(pipe(pfd) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error opening first pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }   

    if(pipe(pfd1) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error opening second pipe\n");
                exit(1);
        }

    if(pipe(pfd2) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error opening third pipe\n");
                exit(1);
        }



    /*child1*/
    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Error forking child1!\n");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            /*closing unnecessary pipe ends*/
            if(close(pfd[1]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing writing end of first pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if(close(pfd1[0]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing reading end of second pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if(close(pfd1[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
            if(close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing reading end of third pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            /*reading from first pipe*/
            char *words1=" ";
            ssize_t numRead;    
            numRead=read(pfd[0],words1,strlen(words1));
            if(numRead == -1);
            {
                printf("Error reading from first pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            fprintf(f,"First child pid_%d received data from parent pid_%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            fflush(f);

            /*closing reading end of first pipe*/
            if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing reading end of first pipr\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            /*counting vowels from received words*/
            /*if even, swapping them in pairs*/
            /*concatenating each word with the number of vowels*/
            char *vowels = "aeiou";
            int i;
            char *words2=" ";
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(words1); )
            {
                if(isspace(words1[i]))
                {
                sprintf(words2,"%s",words1[i++]);
                continue;
                }

                int start = i;

                for (; i < strlen(words1) && !isspace(words1[i]); i++);

                    char *word = words1 + start;
                    int word_len = i - start;
                    int vowel_count = str_count_in_chars(word, words1 + i, vowels);

                     if (vowel_count % 2 == 0) {
                          str_swap_in_chars(word_len, &word, vowels);
                     }
                sprintf(words2,"%.*s_%dvow",word_len,word,vowel_count);
            }       

            fprintf(f,"First child pid_%d made the needed modifications\n",getpid());
            fflush(f);

            /*sending the words to third child*/
            ssize_t stat;
              stat=write(pfd2[1],words2,strlen(words2));
             if(stat<0)
                  {
                        printf("Error writing to third pipe!\n");
                        exit(1);
                   }


            fprintf(f,"First child pid_%d sent the modified data to third child",getpid());
            fflush(f);

            /*closing writing end of third pipe*/
            if(close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of third pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }



        default:
            break;
    }


    /*child2*/
    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
                        printf("Error forking child1!\n");
                        exit(1);
                case 0:
            /*closing unnecessary pipe ends*/
            if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing reading end of first pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if(close(pfd[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of first pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
            if(close(pfd1[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
            if(close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing reading end of third pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

             /*reading from second pipe*/
                        char *words3=" ";
            ssize_t numRead;
                        numRead=read(pfd1[0],words3,strlen(words3));
            if(numRead == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error reading from second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        fprintf(f,"Second child pid_%d received data from parent pid_%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
                        fflush(f);

            /*closing reading end of second pipe*/
                        if(close(pfd1[0]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing reading end of second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

            /*counting consonants from received words*/
                        /*if even, swapping them in pairs*/
                        /*concatenating each word with the number of consonants*/
            char *cons = "qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm";
                        int i;
                        char *words4=" ";
                        for(i = 0; i < strlen(words3); )
                        {
                                if(isspace(words3[i]))
                                {
                                sprintf(words4,"%s",words3[i++]);
                                continue;
                                }

                                int start = i;

                                for (; i < strlen(words3) && !isspace(words3[i]); i++);

                                char *word = words3 + start;
                                int word_len = i - start;
                                int cons_count = str_count_in_chars(word, words3 + i, cons);

                                 if (cons_count % 2 == 0) {
                                  str_swap_in_chars(word_len, &word, cons);
                                 }
                                sprintf(words4,"%.*s_%dvow",word_len,word,cons_count);
                        }


                        fprintf(f,"Second child pid_%d made the needed modifications\n",getpid());
                        fflush(f);

                        /*sending the words to third child*/
            ssize_t stat;
            stat=write(pfd2[1],words4,strlen(words4));
            if(stat<0)
                          {
                                printf("Error writing to third pipe!\n");
                                exit(1);
                           }


                        fprintf(f,"Second child pid_%d sent the modified data to third child",getpid());
                        fflush(f);

                        /*closing writing end of third pipe*/
                        if(close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of third pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

                default:
                        break;

    }


    /*child3*/
    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
                        printf("Error forking child1!\n");
                        exit(1);
                case 0:
            /*closing unnecessary pipe ends*/
                        if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing reading end of first pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                        if(close(pfd[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of first pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                        if(close(pfd1[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
            if(close(pfd1[0]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing reading end of second pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        if(close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error closing writing end of third pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

            /*reading from third pipe*/
            char *words5=" ";
            FILE *h = fopen("output.dat","w");
            ssize_t numRead;

            numRead=read(pfd2[0],words5,strlen(words5));
            if(numRead == -1)
                        {
                                printf("Error reading from third pipe\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        fprintf(f,"Third child pid_%d received data\n",getpid());
                        fflush(f);

            /*closing reading end of third pipe*/
            if(close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
            {
                printf("Error closing reading end of third pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            /*printing received content to file*/
            if(h)
            {
                fputs(words5,h);
            }
            else { printf("Failed to open file\n");}

            fclose(h);

            fprintf(f,"Third child pid_%d printed data to file\n",getpid());
            fflush(f);
                default:
                        break;

    }

    /*parent*/

       if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(close(pfd1[0]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


    g = fopen("input.dat","r");

    /*reading n words from file and sending it to child1 and child2*/
    char *words = file_to_str(g,n);
    printf("%s\n",words);   
    int words_len = strlen(words);
    ssize_t stat;
    stat=write(pfd[1],words,words_len);
    if(stat<0)
    {
        printf("Error writing to first pipe!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(close(pfd[1]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    fprintf(f,"parent pid_%d sent data to child1\n",getpid());
    fflush(f);

    stat=write(pfd1[1],words,words_len);
    if(stat<0)
    {
        printf("Error writing to second pipe!\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    fprintf(f,"parent pid_%d sent data to child2\n",getpid());
    fflush(f);
    fclose(g);


        if(close(pfd1[1]) == -1)
        {
                printf("Error closing reading end of the pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



    fclose(f);

    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

**EDIT** 
After making some modifications in the code with the help of a debugger the program still doesn't work. When I execute the program I get the following errors:

```
-bash-4.1$ gcc program.c -o p
-bash-4.1$ ./p 4
Error reding from first pipe
Error reading from second pipe
Error closing reading end of the pipe.
```

And the content of log.dat file is the following:

```
-bash-4.1$ more log.dat
parent pid_61202 sent data to child1
parent pid_61202 sent data to child2
Third child pid_61205 received data
Third child pid_61205 printed data to file
```

Comment: There is a _lot_ of code here, and yet what you've posted does not compile. Please provide a _minimal_, complete example. You may also benefit from stepping through the code with a debugger, bisecting the program to find the first failure point.

Comment: Your first `realloc` call in `file_to_str` is using a size of zero.  I believe `realloc` is free to return a `NULL` pointer in that case, which would cause your error.  More to the point, using `i * buf_len` doesn't make sense, especially when `i` is zero.

Comment: It is strange that you affirm that the code doesn't compile. I get the error from the second child that reading from the second pipe failed.

Comment: I fixed the realloc to iterate from 1, this may have caused one error.

Comment: Okay, so i changed a few things with the debugger, now it should compile. Unfortunately the program is still not working.

Comment: Please fix code indentation. For your own sanity, I advise to write readable functions and code and split very long function into multiple functions. `char *words4=" ";` `sprintf(words4,. ..` is invalid. You can't write into a string literal. Also to protect against bugs use `snprintf` when possible. All the `/*closing unnecessary pipe ends*/
                        if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)` could use a loop.. `char *words5=" "; numRead=read(pfd2[0],words5,strlen(words5));` is invalid, you can't write to string literal. Please revise your knowledge about strings, `strlen` and memory ownership.

Comment: Is ``char *words4=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);`` the right way ?